# How to correctly config LogStash to read from RabbitMQ and write output to file?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, rabbitmq, logstash

I want to read messages posted by RabbitMQ using LogStash and writing the response as one JSON line per file into a folder locally.

I have installed Docker desktop and pulled LogStash docker image.

I created a `config` folder which contains the following `logstash.conf` file

```
#logstash.conf
input {
  rabbitmq{
    host => "xxxxx.com"
    port => 5672
    heartbeat => 30
    durable => true
    exchange => "xxxxx"
    exchange_type => "topic"
    user-id => "xxxx"
    password => "xxxx"
    key => "#xxxx#"
    queue => "xxxxx"}}


   output{
     file {
       path => "C:/logtest"}
     }
   }
```

I then in Windows CMD write `docker run --rm -it -v C:/logstashconfig/ docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.0.1`

But I get errors.

`Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"No Available connections", :class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::NoConnectionAvailableError"}`

And Warning.

`Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch: Name or service not known"}`

So do I have install something else also, like ElasticSearch? Or do I have to change something in my config file to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to send monitoring information to an elasticsearch server which is identified as `elasticsearch:9200` in logstash.yml, or you might have a pipeline that has a `elasticsearch` output. Either disable it or correct the host to point to a real elasticsearch server.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the documentation :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/master/docker-config.html

By default, logstash will look for configuration in pipeline folder. You have to create pipeline folder with logstash.conf and logstash.yml files.
I had same problem and just putting empty logstash.yml file solved it

Comment: Okay! I will look at that. How do I access this folder from Windows when I am running Linux containers?